# Setear adecuadamente el id en el DTO y en el Mapper

Tags: java, jhipster

Estoy trabajado en una app en Jhipster apenas estoy aprendiendo, tengo un problema para Setear el Id de una relación.

La relación se llama coordinador es una relación entre mi entidad Usuario y ExtendedUser que es una entidad que cree para añadir datos extras a la entidad usuario, ya que no se puede moficar en Jhispter directamente.

ExtendedUserDTO extende a UserDTO.

Así que tengo para comenzar.

En **ExtendedUser.java**

```
 @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("")
    //private User coordinador; 
    private Long coordinadorId; 

public Long getCoordinadorId() {
    return coordinadorId;
}

public void setCoordinadorId(Long id) {
    this.coordinadorId = id;
}
```

Creo que aquí podría esta mi error, pues Jhipster lo sabia generado como un User no como un Long.

En **extendedUserDTO.java**

```
package com.gits.sigem.service.dto;

import com.gits.sigem.domain.User;
import com.gits.sigem.domain.Area;
import com.gits.sigem.domain.Desarrollo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;

/**
 * A DTO for the ExtendedUser entity.
 */
public class ExtendedUserDTO extends UserDTO implements Serializable {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExtendedUserDTO.class);
    private Long id;
    private String puesto;

    private BigDecimal sueldo;

    private LocalDate fechaIngreso;

    private Long usuarioId;

    private Long coordinadorId;

    private Set<Area> areas = new HashSet<>();

    //private User coordinador;

    private Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos = new HashSet<>();

    public ExtendedUserDTO(){

    }

    public ExtendedUserDTO(User user){
        super(user);
        this.puesto = user.getExtendedUser().getPuesto();
        this.sueldo = user.getExtendedUser().getSueldo();
        this.fechaIngreso = user.getExtendedUser().getFechaIngreso();
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.usuarioId = user.getId();
        this.coordinadorId = user.getExtendedUser().getCoordinadorId();
        this.desarrollos = user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos());
        this.desarrollos = user.getExtendedUser().getDesarrollos();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getExtendedUser().getAreas());
        this.areas = user.getExtendedUser().getAreas();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPuesto() {
        return puesto;
    }

    public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
        this.puesto = puesto;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }

    public void setSueldo(BigDecimal sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }

    public LocalDate getFechaIngreso() {
        return fechaIngreso;
    }

    public void setFechaIngreso(LocalDate fechaIngreso) {
        this.fechaIngreso = fechaIngreso;
    }

    public Long getUsuarioId() {
        return usuarioId;
    }

    public void setUsuarioId(Long userId) {
        this.usuarioId = userId;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }


    /*public User getCoordinador() {
        return coordinador;
    }

    public void setCoordinador(User user) {
        this.coordinador = user;
    }*/


    public Set<Area> getAreas() {
        return areas;
    }

    public void setAreas(Set<Area> areas) {
        this.areas = areas;
    }

    public Set<Desarrollo> getDesarrollos() {
        return desarrollos;
    }

    public void setDesarrollos(Set<Desarrollo> desarrollos) {
        this.desarrollos = desarrollos;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        ExtendedUserDTO extendedUserDTO = (ExtendedUserDTO) o;
        if (extendedUserDTO.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), extendedUserDTO.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExtendedUserDTO{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", puesto='" + getPuesto() + "'" +
            ", sueldo=" + getSueldo() +
            ", fechaIngreso='" + getFechaIngreso() + "'" +
            ", usuario=" + getUsuarioId() +
            ", coordinador=" + getCoordinadorId() +
            "}";
    }
}
```

ya con esto me carga los usuarios seleccionados en en el Select de mi componente de Angular, pero como traigo las dos entidades en un solo DTO al momento de guardar en el **UserResource.java** es cuando ya no se si lo estoy haciendo bien:

```
   Optional<UserDTO> updatedUser = userService.updateUser(extendedUserDTO);
        ExtendedUser updateExtendedUser = existingUser.get().getExtendedUser();
        updateExtendedUser.setPuesto(extendedUserDTO.getPuesto());
        updateExtendedUser.setSueldo(extendedUserDTO.getSueldo());
        updateExtendedUser.setFechaIngreso(extendedUserDTO.getFechaIngreso());
        updateExtendedUser.setAreas(extendedUserDTO.getAreas());
        updateExtendedUser.setDesarrollos(extendedUserDTO.getDesarrollos());
        updateExtendedUser.setCoordinadorId(extendedUserDTO.getCoordinadorId());
        extendedUserService.save(updateExtendedUser);
```

Ni tampoco si esta correcto mi **ExtendedUserMapper.java**

```
 @Mapping(source = "usuario.id", target = "usuarioId")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinadorId", target = "coordinadorId")
    ExtendedUserDTO toDto(ExtendedUser extendedUser);

    @Mapping(source = "usuarioId", target = "usuario")
    @Mapping(source = "coordinadorId", target = "coordinadorId")
```

Pues me esta dando un error (no incluyo todo el error):

```
    2019-01-15 16:27:26.810  WARN 3569 --- [igem-Executor-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@60cd4452 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08003), ErrorCode(0)

    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:767)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.getAutoCommit(PgConnection.java:728)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection.rollback(JdbcConnection.java:336)


2019-01-15 16:27:26.814  WARN 3569 --- [igem-Executor-1] liquibase                                : Failed to restore the auto commit to true
2019-01-15 16:27:26.814 ERROR 3569 --- [igem-Executor-1] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

2019-01-15 16:27:26.862 ERROR 3569 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Lo que me gustaría es que alguien me explicara como setear apropiadamente mi **coordinador_id**

Comment: Usa la anotacion en el campo clave @ID

Comment: @AndyC no seria mejor obtenerlo como un objeto Usuario?

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugerencia es usar hibernate 5 con JPA2. Aqui un ejemplo de como aplicarlo a traves de spring

Clase Usuario (Entidad que con la estructura de la tabla de la base de datos.)

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Usuarios {

@Id 
private String tokenUsuario;
//@NotNull
private String usuario;
//@NotNull
private String correo;
//@NotNull
private String telefono;

private String imagenPerfil;
//@NotNull 
private Long fecha;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuarios", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonBackReference(value = "pines-usuario")
private Set<Pines> pines;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "usuarios", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonBackReference(value = "seguridad-usuarios")
private Seguridad seguridad;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "usuarios", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonBackReference(value = "tokens-usuarios")
private Tokens tokens;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuarios", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
@JsonBackReference(value = "contratacion-usuario")
private Set<Contratacion> contratacion;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuarios", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
@JsonBackReference(value = "servicios-usuario")
private Set<Servicios> servicios;


public String getTokenUsuario() {
    return tokenUsuario;
}
public void setTokenUsuario(String tokenUsuario) {
    this.tokenUsuario = tokenUsuario;
}
public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}
public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}
public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}
public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}
public Long getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}
public void setFecha(Long fecha) {
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getImagenPerfil() {
    return imagenPerfil;
}
public void setImagenPerfil(String imagenPerfil) {
    this.imagenPerfil = imagenPerfil;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Usuarios [tokenUsuario=" + tokenUsuario + ", usuario=" + usuario + ", correo=" + correo + ", telefono="
            + telefono + ", fecha=" + fecha + ", pines=" + pines + "]";
}

public Seguridad getSeguridad() {
    return seguridad;
}
public void setSeguridad(Seguridad seguridad) {
    this.seguridad = seguridad;
}
public Tokens getTokens() {
    return tokens;
}
public void setTokens(Tokens tokens) {
    this.tokens = tokens;
}
public Set<Pines> getPines() {
    return pines;
}
public void setPines(Set<Pines> pines) {
    this.pines = pines;
}
public Set<Contratacion> getContratacion() {
    return contratacion;
}
public void setContratacion(Set<Contratacion> contratacion) {
    this.contratacion = contratacion;
}
public Set<Servicios> getServicios() {
    return servicios;
}
public void setServicios(Set<Servicios> servicios) {
    this.servicios = servicios;
}

}
```

Repositorio. Permite usar la especificacion JPA para acceder a la estructura de consulta de la base de datos mediante hibernate

```
@Repository
public interface UsuariosRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuarios, String> {

Usuarios findByUsuario(String nombreUsuario);

}
```

Servicios. Sirve para realizar las operaciones de interes.

```
@Service
public class UsuariosServiceImpl implements UsuariosService {

@Autowired
private UsuariosRepository usuariosRepository;

@Override
public List<Usuarios> listarLosUsuarios() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return usuariosRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Usuarios buscarPorToken(String tokenUsuario) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return usuariosRepository.findOne(tokenUsuario);
}

@Override
public Usuarios agregarNuevoUsuario(Usuarios usuario) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return usuariosRepository.save(usuario);

}

@Override
public Usuarios actualizarUsuario(Usuarios usuario) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return usuariosRepository.save(usuario);
}



@Override
public void borrarUsuario(String tokenUsuario) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    usuariosRepository.delete(tokenUsuario);

}

@Override
public Usuarios buscarPorUsuario(String nombreUsuario) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return usuariosRepository.findByUsuario(nombreUsuario);
}




}
```